# AVPlayer seek not always accurate

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I am having an issue with AVPlayer seek. Current code:

```
self.player?.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: Double(startSeconds), preferredTimescale: 600)
```

This works about 80% of the time. But sometimes it does't seek to the correct position and instead starts over at 0.0.

I attempted this way:

```
let time = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(startSeconds), timescale: 1)
self.player?.seek(to: time, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
```

This works 100% of the time but it's **very** slow to seek.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default tolerance value is infinity(when not specified), but usually real difference from the requested value is about a second - this allows seek to be fast.

If in your case it is jumping to the file start, it's probably because your file was not correctly encoded.

If you cannot change source of your files, the best you can do is specifying tolerance more than zero, but not too big. Like ±1 sec. The less tolerance you have the longer seek would perform, so try to find some balance.

Comment: Tolerance uses `CMTime`, would I just init like : `let tolerance = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 1) ` ?

Comment: @Kex no, you can use seconds initializer: `CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 44100)`

Comment: @Kex actually your variant should work too, but the best way is taking `preferredTimescale` from your asset

Comment: where do you get 44100 from? Also is it okay that I use `1` as my timeScale for the `time` property?

Comment: @Kex 44100 is just a default timescale for audio, for video default one is 600(I should've used it in my example). I'd say that you better use `asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first?.naturalTimeScale` for all calculations with video. In some cases `1` will work, but it's a bad practice.